# How do I integrate asp.net Custom WebHook API with Azure Logic App

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

I'm implementing C# WebAPI for custom WebHook to integrate with LogicApp workflow. WebAPI is having action which will send message to serviebus queue, this message is been picked-up by azure function and will process the same and send response to queue. Once the response is received webhook will send the confirmation to the initial requestor.

I've developed all the pieces but not sure how do I integrate/bring them together as flow using logic apps.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

When using an HTTP connector in logic apps, you may utilize them to make outgoing calls to other services.

[image]

For more information on this, you can refer [Call service endpoints over HTTP or HTTPS from Azure Logic Apps - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http)

#### Updated Answer

[image]

Comment: if you could ass the missing pieces of the flow like functions, webhooks and their integration to complete.

Comment: @Aryan As you have mentioned that you already have a web API action in place where the web API sends message to service bus which is followed by azure functions. As per my understanding, I thought this was the ask and so I have provided how you could call the web API. If my understanding is wrong please clarify or try adding more details to your question.

Comment: @Aryan, If you meant to build the flow in logic apps I have updated the flow of logic app and added to my answer.

Comment: could you help me understand how we can make logic app wait-respond to events for custom webhooks(custom api's)?

Comment: @Aryan, you can enable [Asynchronous request-response behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#asynchronous-request-response-behavior) for HTTP based actions